# How to see files under DVC TRACKED section in VS code after adding the folder using 'dvc add'?

Tags: visual-studio-code, dvc

After setting up the DVC in my project, I am able to see modifications, commit and push through command line but VScode doesn't show anything in **'DVC TRACKED'** section.

First, I set up my DVC project using the below:

```
-git init
-dvc init

# added the cache and .dvc file
-mkdir data
-dvc add data/
-git commit

-git add data.dvc .gitignore

#setting up local storage for test as remote
-mkdir temp
-dvc remote add -d remote temp
```

Now, any changes that I am doing to data folder is showing up as a change if I do `dvc status`. I am  able to do `dvc commit` and `dvc push` in command line.

[image]

But when I installed the extension DVC in VScode. The section **'DVC tracked'** doesn't show anything. Also the files in data folder doesn't show any highlight if I make changes to them.

[image]

Is there any changes that I need to make in setting to show these data changes in dvc track? I have just installed the extension in VScode.

`Note:` I have added the /data folder to .gitignore.

Comment: Could you please run `dvc version` and share the result?

Comment: @Shcheklein --DVC version: 3.30.1 (pip)
-------------------------

Platform: Python 3.8.10 on Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0
Subprojects:

        dvc_data = 2.22.1

        dvc_objects = 1.2.0

        dvc_render = 0.6.0

        dvc_task = 0.3.0

        scmrepo = 1.5.0

Supports:

        http (aiohttp = 3.9.1, aiohttp-retry = 2.8.3),
        https (aiohttp = 3.9.1, aiohttp-retry = 2.8.3)

Config:

        Global: C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\iterative\dvc
        System: C:\ProgramData\iterative\dvc

Comment: @Shcheklein  sorry, tried but not able to format the reply

Comment: Nw. Could you please try to upgrade it to the most recent version. I suspect one particular bug in this case that we fixed recently. It might help to see if that was the case. Btw, also, come to https://github.com/iterative/vscode-dvc with this type of issues - it'll be easier to followup and fix it. We are responsive there.